# render multi array data in react native flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have been using javascript `map` function to render lists in react native. through `js map` i am able to use multiple arrays. ex:

```
names=["a","b","c"];
price=[1,2,3];
```

i use

```
`this.state.names.map((item,i)=>(<Item name=item price = 
 this.state.price[i] />))`
```

code to render the Item list. 
I am planning to move to using React native FlatList components and am wondering if its possible to use the multi arrays as used in `js map`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**,  use it in a same way you are using with `js map`

```
<FlatList data={this.state.names}
          extraData={this.state}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => <Item name=item price = this.state.price[index] /> }
          />
```

**Suggestion :** It is not good practice to use data like this, if you have name and price, make it one array with JSON objects.

```
var data= [{name:"a",price:1},{name:"b",price:2},{name:"c",price:3}]
```